# Using the split() or find() function in python

Tags: python, string, find

Am writing a program that opens a file and looks for line which are like this:

```
X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475.
```

I want to use the split and find function to extract these lines and put it in a variable. This is the code I have written:

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) == 0:
    fname = 'mbox-short.txt'
fh = open(fname,'r')
total = 0
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"): continue
```

Please, Please I am now beginning in python so please give me something simple which I can understand to help me later on. Please, Please.

Comment: Why not just `if line = X-DSPAM-Confidence:    0.8475. `?

Comment: @Arman I doubt the value is the same every time

Comment: @wilbur , so why `not` in if ? with out `not` it's true I think

Comment: To the already posted answers I can only add: people, try using exception handling every once in a while when working with files... LOL

Answer (score 0):

You're very close, you just need to add a statement below the continue adding the line to a `list`.

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) == 0:
    fname = 'mbox-short.txt'
fh = open(fname,'r')
total = 0
lines = []
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
        continue
    lines.append(line) # will only execute if the continue is not executed
fh.close()
```

You should also look at the [`with`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) keyword for opening files - it's much safer and easier. You would use it like this (I also swapped the logic of your `if` - saves you a line and a needless continue):

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) == 0:
    fname = 'mbox-short.txt'
total = 0
good_lines = []
with open(fname,'r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
            good_lines.append(line)
```

If you just want the values, you can do a list comprehension with the `good_lines` list like this:

```
values = [ l.split()[1] for l in good_lines ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only wrong part is `not` in if :

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
if len(fname) == 0:
    fname = 'mbox-short.txt'
fh = open(fname,'r')
total = 0
lines = []
for line in fh:
    if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"): 
        lines.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

First receive the input with `raw_input()`

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
```

Then check if the input string is empty:

```
if not fname:
    fname = 'mbox-short.txt'
```

Then, open the file and read it line by line:

```
lines = []
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:"):
            lines.append(line)
```

The `with open() as file` statement just ensures that the file object gets closed when you don't need it anymore. (`file.close()` is called automatically upon exiting out of the `with` clause)

Answer (score 0):

I know where this one is coming from as I've done it myself some time ago. As far as I remember you need to calculate the average :)

```
fname = raw_input("Enter file name: ")
fh = open(fname)
count = 0
sum = 0
for line in fh:
    if not line.startswith("X-DSPAM-Confidence:") : continue
    count = count + 1
    pos = line.find(' ')
    sum = sum + float(line[pos:])
average = sum/count
```